# PHP login using session return blank page after submit form

Tags: php, session

I want a Login with Session I have Tried This But Doesn't Work.

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
 ?>
<form method="post" name="login" action="login.php">
<label for="name" class="labelname"> Username </label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="userid" required="required" /><br />
<label for="name" class="labelname"> Password </label>
 <input type="password" name="password" id="passid" required="required"  /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  value="Login" />
 </form>
```

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
session_start();
{
$user=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$fetch=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `login` WHERE 
                     username='$user' and password='$pass'");
$count=mysql_num_rows($fetch);
if($count!="")
{
session_register("sessionusername");
$_SESSION['login_username']=$user;
header("Location:profile.php"); 
}
else
{
   header('Location:index.php');
}

}
?>
```

**SESSION.PHP**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();
$check=$_SESSION['login_username'];
 $session=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM `login` WHERE username='$check'     ");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($session);
$login_session=$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session))
{
header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
```

**PROFILE.PHP**

```
<?php
 include("session.php");
 ?>
 <h3 align="center"> Hellow <?php echo $login_session; ?></h3> 
 <h2 align="center" >Welcome to login system</h2> 
 <h4 align="center">  click here to <a href="logout.php">LogOut</a> </h4>
```

So Here What's Wrong With My code, It doesn't work, When I click Login, It stays Empty Page. Please Fix It Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Empty page OR Blank page means **Syntax Error**. Please, check your php_error_log or set `ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your file to see What kind of error.

Comment: `session_register` that's deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php - so is `mysql_`

Comment: *"But Doesn't Work."* - That doesn't help us.

Comment: Also. Why are you opening blanket `{` right after `session_start();` at line 4 in login.php? You need to remove another `}` at the end of file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its syntax error.

Remove your `{` right after `session_start();` at line 4 and `}` at the end of file in login.php.

Keep you code like this:

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');
    session_start();
    $user=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $fetch=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `login` WHERE 
                 username='$user' and password='$pass'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($fetch);
    if($count!="")
    {
        session_register("sessionusername");
        $_SESSION['login_username']=$user;
        header("Location:profile.php"); 
         exit;
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location:index.php');
         exit;
    } 

?>
```

Did you notice the difference?

**UPDATE**

As Fred -ii- mentioned in comments:

> session_register() function This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

- Also, consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: Not to mention [session_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) *This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.* - along with their MySQL function. So let's hope the OP doesn't come back and says it again *"It doesn't work"* - ah, God love 'em. Edit: I must be psychic.

Comment: @bcesars       still doesn't work.

Comment: I'll update with your notice @Fred-ii-. Thanks. PawanKalyan. Did you see your php_error_log and found out what kind of error. It has other errors in your script code.

Comment: @PawanKalyan *Oh?!* - Err... great and you're welcome :) And what did it?

Comment: Sidenote: It's best to place `include('config.php');` under `session_start();` if the DB has errors, it will signal an headers already sent notice.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  session_register that's deprecated, I have removed this, it works for me now, Thanks buddy.

Comment: @PawanKalyan *Ah...*, I love happy endings! *Cheers!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Cheers buddy, You rocks..

Comment: @PawanKalyan Thank you. Let's wrap it all up and see some "green" here! lol the "green ticky" I mean ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove unused '{' in line 4, and '}' in line 21 in you LOGIN.php

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that check in your `session.php`? Change it to this, this is enough and doesn't stress the DB all the time.

Also, I see you are training to do your first logins, you should learn to use the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) class. Also, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for security and [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) the password. Save only the hashed password and salt to your database.

Do it right the first time, do it right all the time. ;) Good luck!

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_username'])) {
    header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
```